# jQuery - Sticky sidebar after scroll, doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css, sticky

I want to use code from [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/livibetter/HV9HM/) to make a sticky sidebar. My purpose is to make the sidebar stick to top when I scroll past it. I try to adapt this method on my code but it doesn't work.

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
  sticky_relocate();
});

$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 400) {
    $('.navbar-bottom').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.navbar-bottom').fadeOut();
  }
});

function sticky_relocate() {
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top = $('#sidebar-anchor').offset().top;
  if (window_top > div_top) {
    $('.sidebar').addClass('sticky');
    $('#sidebar-anchor').height($('#sticky').outerHeight());
  } else {
    $('.sidebar').removeClass('sticky');
    $('#sidebar-anchor').height(0);
  }
}
```

```css
.sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 224px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}
.sticky {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar-anchor"></div>
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <input class="search-shop" type="text" placeholder="Cari di Toko Ini">
    <img class="magnifier-shop" src="img/search-grey.png">
  </div>
  <div class="filter">
    <div class="filter-accordion">
      Filter
      <span>
          <img class="arrow-down" src="img/down.png">
         </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="etalase">
    <h2>Etalase</h2>
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><span class="etalase-name">Semua Etalase</span><span class="etalase-count">193</span>
      </li>
      <li><span class="etalase-name">Produk Terjual</span><span class="etalase-count">193</span>
      </li>
      <li><span class="etalase-name">Tas Slempang</span><span class="etalase-count">45</span>
      </li>
      <li><span class="etalase-name">Tas Ransel</span><span class="etalase-count">39</span>
      </li>
      <li><span class="etalase-name">JAKET HOODIE</span><span class="etalase-count">39</span>
      </li>
      <li><span class="etalase-name">Gadget 2nd</span><span class="etalase-count">39</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="notes">
    <div class="notes-title">Cek sebelum berbelanja</div>
    <ul>
      <li>Perihal Stok, Pengiriman, dan Pemesanan</li>
      <li>Kontak Saya</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery. As you can see I also use scrolling method to stick a navbar and it works, but the sticky sidebar doesn't work.

```
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
  sticky_relocate();
});

$(document).scroll(function() {
 var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 400) {
    $('.navbar-bottom').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.navbar-bottom').fadeOut();
  }
});

function sticky_relocate() {
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top = $('#sidebar-anchor').offset().top;
  if (window_top > div_top) {
    $('.sidebar').addClass('sticky');
    $('#sidebar-anchor').height($('#sticky').outerHeight());
  } else {
    $('.sidebar').removeClass('sticky');
    $('#sidebar-anchor').height(0);
  }
}
```

After I scroll past the sidebar, it doesn't stick to top and my main content (on the right of the sidebar) occupy the space of the sidebar and overlay it. I have no idea why would this happen.

Thank you, any idea appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sticky sidebar does not work because, when you set its position to `fixed`, it is removed from the document flow, it is positioned relative to the viewport and it does not leave a gap in the page where it would normally have been located.

My suggestion is to create a child `div` inside the `.sidebar` - let's name it `.sidebar-content`, which will behave as a sticky element.
Also, when the `.sidebar-content` becomes sticky, we must set the appropiate height to its parent, in order to prevent the other content from the page to  get over our sidebar.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/bdqLwzfm/.

---

Also, if you have a lot of scroll events in the page, I would suggest trying the following plugin: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/.
It has an extension for sticky elements: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/.

---

More info about CSS position property:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/
https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/position/

Comment: Now it works, thank you! The one that made a problem is the sidebar parent class that has a transform property. After I remove it, it works like a charm :)